# Strange process running cause high 100% CPU usage

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-9.3

I am having problem with strange Process running by user Postgres:

[image: Htop showing]

I had tried killing it in htop (SIGTERM), but it then restarted immediately. It only stopped when I removed the execution file /tmp/suhahoi.

But the next day, the strange file was automatically created and ran again. Below is the chart from google cloud showing the high CPU usage:
[image: Google cloud high CPU usage]

Does anyone know what it is and how I can prevent this from happening?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server seems to be hacked. It appears to be downloading and running an executable file called suhahoi.

The htop command shows the arguments given to this executable file. The arguments seem to be base64 encoded. You can try to base64 decode the argument.

I suggest you install an anti virus script such as ClamAV and also anti malware script such as rkhunter. If that does not fix your problem, then you should reinstall your server.

Comment: I find out that my server was hacked, someone is using it for mining bitcoin. Thank you for your help!

Comment: i'm facing this issue how to fix it?

Comment: Well as mentioned in the answer, you should install an anti virus script such as ClamAV and also anti malware script like RKHunter

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience. Somebody has got into your server via postgres db.
If you go into your `/var/lib/postgresql/` and check the content of the folder with `ls -lah`, you might be seeing the strange and suspicious hidden folders containing some bash scripts. Content of the bash scripts might be `base64` encoded.
In my case, I have found out that somebody has been mining monero via my virtual servers.

**How I have fixed it:**

- close 5432 port to public (use ssh tunnels)
- change password for db user
- remove all the suspicious scripts in mentioned postgres folder